# JTagging an Atmel ATF1500 CPLD

Tags: atmel, jtag, programmable-logic, isp

**Intentions**

I'm learning how to use CPLDs and I thought a good one to start with is the Atmel ATF1500AL-TQFP44.

**Whats the deal**

The datasheet provides no information about programming the CPLD; also, the pin configuration description does not clearly identify any pins as the ones for programming.

The document from Atmel titled *ATF15xx In-System Programming* **does not identify the ATF1500AL explicitly covered under Table 3-1**, where pins 1, 32, 7, and 26 are the programming pins. I could be overthinking!

If there is no method to accomplish in-system programming using a microprocessor, I'll need to find a different chip more suitable for someone lost at sea.

Comment: Openocd supposedly supports some of these devices. There may be some hints in their docs.

Comment: That helps with the ISP part. Now if I could only figure out what (free) tool to use to design the logic.

Comment: A quick google will tell you that the Altera max7000 range is identical. You can use an old version of their tools.  Save yourself the grief and use modern devices with level translators if you need 5V logic.